# Forcing Garbage Collection

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2000

Is there a way to force garbage collection in VBA/Excel 2000?

This question refers to the Macro language in Excel.
Not using VB .NET to manipulate Excel. So GC.collect() won't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot take advantage of garbage collection provided by the .NET Framework when using straight VBA. [Perhaps this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/122259.aspx) by Eric Lippert will be helpful

Comment: I did not know that VBA used reference counting and didn't support clean up of circular references. That might be the underlaying problem.  
The original problem was that sometimes workbooks didn't close correctly when closed and de-referenced in class destructors. I thought the problem came from that the object hadn't been collected yet. Most likely I have a circular reference some wheyer that come into play some times. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I agree, you can't do it directly from VBA. But you actually CAN take advantage of the .NET's GC if you reference a COM library. See [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398477/how-to-set-application-name-in-adodb-connection-string/20406284#20406284), specifically the part about the `.Dispose()` method called from VBA.

Answer (score 7):

You can't force GC in VBA, but it's good to set to Nothing the global variables.

The article mentioned by kd7 says it's useless to set to Nothing the local variables before they go out of scope, but doesn't talk about the global variables.

In VBA the global variables defined in a module remain alive through the whole Excel session, i.e. until the document containing the VBA module that defines them closed.

So don't put useless `Set O = Nothing` when O is local, but do it when it's global.

Answer (score 3):

VBA/Excel does not have garbage collection, like old VB. Instead of GC, it uses reference counting. Memory is freed when you set a pointer to nothing (or when variable goes out of scope). Like in old VB it means that circular references are never freed.

Comment: Example of a known issue here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/280454/password-prompt-for-vba-project-appears-after-excel-quits