# How to set "Application Name" in ADODB connection string

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, connection-string, adodb

In .NET I simply use `Application Name = MyApp` inside the connection string, but when using ADO connection through VBA the Activity Monitor of the SQL Server Management Studio always shows `Microsoft Office 2010` in `Processes` on the `Application` column no matter what name I set on the VBA code.

```vb
conn.ConnectionString = "UID=" & UID & ";PWD=" & PWD & ";DSN=" & DSN & _
    ";Application Name = MyApp"
```

How can I set the application name for monitoring purposes?

Comment: Ahh I see VBA connection string doesn't support he Application Name attribute. The only way I can think of solving this is exposing your own COM library and referencing it from VBA. Your own library would connect to the database via .NET framework which allows you to use the Applcation Name parameter. Fancy a solution using a COM library let me know I could answer that I think @SysDragon

Comment: You can easily set the application name in the connection string via VBA, `Application Name` is just the wrong keyword. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41231500/6884).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ahh I see VBA connection string doesn't support the *`Application Name`* attribute. It simply isn't being recognized when used within VBA. The only way I can think of solving this at the moment it's to return an `ADODB.Connection` object from a COM C# library.

Your own COM library would return an ADODB.Connection object with a predefined connection string which seem to work in .NET. You will be connecting to the database using a VBA ADODB.Connection object but with a substituted object reference. Instead of

`Set cn = new ADODB.Connection` you will use a `GetConection()` method exposed by your own library.

```
Dim cn as ADODB.Connection
Set cn = yourCOMlibrary.GetConnection
```

## here are the steps

Download and install [Visual Studio Express for Windows (*FREE*)](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-desktop)

**Open it as Administrator** and create a New Project. Select *`Visual C#`* then *`Class Library`* and rename it to *`MyConnection`*

[image]

In the *Solution Explorer*, rename *`Class1.cs`* to *`ServerConnection.cs`*

[image]

Right click your *`MyConnection`* project in the *Solution Explorer* and select *`Add Reference`*

Type `activeX` in the search box and tick the `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library`

[image]

Copy and paste the below code into the *`ServerConnection.cs`* completely replacing whatever is in the file.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using ADODB;

namespace MyConnection
{
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual),
    Guid("32A5A235-DA9F-47F0-B02C-9243315F55FD")]
    public interface INetConnection
    {
        Connection GetConnection();
        void Dispose();
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("4E7C6DA2-2606-4100-97BB-AB11D85E54A3")]
    public class ServerConnection : INetConnection, IDisposable
    {
        private Connection cn;

        private string cnStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=SERVER\\DB; Initial Catalog=default_catalog; User ID=username; Password=password;Application Name=MyNetConnection";

        public Connection GetConnection()
        {
            cn = new Connection();
            cn.ConnectionString = cnStr;
            return cn;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            cn = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}
```

**Locate the `cnStr` variable in the code and UPDATE your connection string details.**

Note: if you are unsure about the connection string you should use see [ALL CONNECTION STRINGS](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Click on TOOLs in Visual Studio and CREATE GUID

Replace the GUIDs with your own and **remove the curly braces so they are in the same format as the ones you see now from the copied code**

[image]

Right click *`MyConnection`* in the *Solution Explorer* and select Properties.

Click the *`Application`* tab on the left side, then *`Assembly Info`* and tick `Make Assembly COM-Visible`

[image]

Click the `*Build*` from the menu on the left and tick `Register For COM Interop`

[image]

Note: If you are developing for 64-bit Office then make sure you change the *`Platform Target`* on the *Build* menu to `x64`! This is mandatory for 64-bit Office COM libraries to avoid any ActiveX related errors.

---

Right click *`MyConnection`* in the *Solution Explorer* and select *`Build`* from the menu.

If everything went OK then your `MyConnection.dll` and `MyConnection.tlb` should be successfully generated. Go to this path now

[image]

```
C:\Users\username\desktop\
```

**or wherever you saved them**

and you should see your files.

[image]

---

Now open Excel and go to VBE. Click `Tools` and select `References`.

Click the <kbd>Browse</kbd> button and navigate to the `MyConnection.tlb`.

Also, add references to `Microsoft ActiveX Object 6.1 Library` - this is so you can use ADODB library.

[image]

Now right click anywhere in the *Project Explorer* window and *Insert* a new *`Module`*

copy and paste the below code to it

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Dim myNetConnection As ServerConnection
    Set myNetConnection = New ServerConnection

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = myNetConnection.GetConnection

    cn.Open

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

    myNetConnection.Dispose

End Sub
```

---

Open SQL Server Management Studio, right click the server and select `Activity Monitor`

[image]

dont close this window

---

Go back to Excel and hit <kbd>F5</kbd> or hit the green *play* button on the ribbon.

[image]

now switch back to SSMS ( SQL Server Management Studio )

and wait for your **custom connection name to appear**! :)

## Here we go! That was easy, wasn't it? :)

[image]

---

This is what is happening.

You are returning an ADODB Connection object from you C# COM library by using `myNetConnection.GetConnection` function

```
Dim myNetConnection As ServerConnection
Set myNetConnection = New ServerConnection

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = myNetConnection.GetConnection
```

It's almost like saying `Set cn = new ADODB.Connection` but with predefined connection string which you did in your C# code.

You can use the `cn` object like a normal ADODB.Connection object within VBA now.

Remember to always `.Close()` the ADODB.Connection. A good programmers practice is to always close anything you open - streams, connections, etc.

You can rely on the Garbage Collector to free references/ memory but I also wrote a `Dispose()` method for you so you can force the GC to run. You can do that to immediately get rid of the Connection so it does not *hang* in the SSMS as opened.

Remember to use `myNetConnection.Dispose` along with the `cn.Close` and you'll be fine.

Note:

This is how I would do it if any one thinks this is wrong or needs to be updates (as being unstable or *unsafe*) please leave a comment.

---

Well, I hope this will be helpful to anyone in the future :)

Comment: Thanks @SysDragon. Are you actually going to use it though?

Comment: I'll try, because I have no Administrator rights on this computer.

Comment: "`Object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found`" on `GetConnection` =/

Comment: Oh, sorry, too little specific. While executing the macro on the Excel it raises that compilation error on `Set conn = myNetConn.GetConnection`

Comment: @SysDragon Ok. do you get intelli-sense after typing `myNetConn.` ? does `GetConnection` and `Dispose` show in the little dropdown?

Comment: Ok. Did you add references to ActiveX in your library? Did it compile sucessfuly?

Comment: Yup, it shows both. And I added the references. When it's going to begin executing the macro shows that compilation error.

Comment: @SysDragon did you change the Platform Target before compiling your dll? If you don't have a 64bit office but a 32bit then you need to change it. Just confirm that for me please

Comment: @SysDragon if your excel is 32bit then change to x86 and retry. Also, restart your computer ;) I have just reproduced the steps and everything works fine for me. So I think it's safe to assume youve done something wrong somewhere :/ just restart your machine and try again mate

Answer (score 1):

The correct keyword to set the application name in an ADODB connection string in VBA is `APP`, not `Application Name`.

Example connection string, copied from an MS Access app I'm working on:

```
DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=xxxx;DATABASE=xxxx;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=xxxx
```