# How to check which IIS application is calling the database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have 2 application (websites) on one IIS and which is calling same remote database. Is there any thing in SQL server which will give me in stored procedure that who is calling :) ?

Comment: Create a SQL username for each website perhaps.

Comment: any other thing :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your connection strings and add <kbd>Application Name</kbd>

> Data Source=myServer;
>        Initial Catalog=myDB;
>        User Id=myUsername;
>        Password=myPassword;
>        Application Name=myApp;

Now when you query sys.processes,program name will be application name

References:
http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2006/10/24/take-advantage-of-application-name/
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Check this thread if you are using VB.NET:
[How to set "Application Name" in ADODB connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398477/how-to-set-application-name-in-adodb-connection-string)

if not above will work

Answer (score 1):

APP_NAME() returns the application name for the current session if set by the application. An another way of identifying the app is to log the app name through the CRUD operation , so that an additional field will be added in the tables to hold the app name.

Comment: `if set by the application`, How and from where application name will will be set?

Comment: conn_string = "Provider=yyyy;Data Source=x.x.x.x;Initial Catalog=dbname;" & _
              "User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Application Name=Testapp;"